# How to compare two richtextbox text using C#

Tags: xml, c#-3.0

I have written a logic to compare two ricttext boxes content, but the output difference text is not highlighted at the expected index. It starts ahead of the expected index. I have given below the logic i have used.

```
private void CompareRichTextContents(RichTextBox target, RichTextBox dest)
    {
        string[] targetLines = target.Lines;
        string[] destLine = dest.Lines;
        List<string> result=targetLines.Except(destLine).ToList<string>();
        foreach (string str in result)
        {

            int lineIndex=Array.IndexOf(targetLines, str);
            int lineCount=0;
            for (int index = 0; index < lineIndex; index++)
            {
                lineCount+=targetLines[index].Length;
            }
            target.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
            target.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
            target.SelectionStart = lineCount;
            target.SelectionLength = str.Length;

        }
    }
```

Thanks,
Lokesh.

Comment: Which line does it highlight, exactly?

Comment: For example, I have the below lines Target Part: 
<sheetPr />
  <dimension ref="C2" />
  <sheetViews>
DestPart

 <sheetPr />
  <sheetViews>

The line should be highlighted from dimension, but it get started from "/> " from the previous line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look for line feeds that may be the problem

Comment: I hope all the contents from the richtext lines are read as string, and its length is same when the line is converted to char array. I dont understand what you mean by line feeds in this part.

Comment: If so can please let me know how to look for line feed

Comment: try lineCount+=targetLines[index].Length+2;

Answer (score 1):

Your method is allright however rich textbox only selects one time further, you have to add 1.

Do as below:

private int CompareRichTextContents(RichTextBox target, RichTextBox dest)
        { 
            int counter = 0;
            string[] targetLines = target.Lines;
            string[] destLine = dest.Lines;
           List result = targetLines.Except(destLine).ToList(); 
            foreach (string str in result)
            {

```
            int lineIndex = Array.IndexOf(targetLines, str);
            int lineCount = 0;
            for (int index = 0; index < lineIndex; index++)
            {
                lineCount += targetLines[index].Length+1;
            }
            target.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
            target.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
           // target.Select(lineCount, str.Length);
             target.SelectionStart = lineCount;
             target.SelectionLength = str.Length;
             counter++;

        }
        return counter; 
    }
```

Now in button click event, call it as many times as many selections. Though this is calling unnecessary time (writing without thinking much) but each time it will select the next one.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           int counter= CompareRichTextContents(this.richTextBox1Body, this.richTextBox2Body);
           for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
               CompareRichTextContents(this.richTextBox1Body, this.richTextBox2Body);
        }
```