# Comparing two RichTextBoxes?

Tags: c#, compare, richtextbox

I'm comparing richTextBox1 and richTextBox2 word by word.

```
// collect words from ritchtextbox1
String[] test = richtextbox1.text.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// find each word test to richtextbox2
// if it is found then change back color of particular word to green of the 
// else change back color of particular word to red in richtextbox1

test = richtextbox2.text.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// find each word in test to richtextbox1
// if it is found then change back color of particular word to green of the 
// else change back color of particular word to red in richtextbox2
```

can any one help me in code i'm little bit poor in syntax.

im taking reference of [mateusz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290863/mateusz) code

```
String[] test = richtextbox1.text.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
String[] test2 = richtextbox2.text.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

bool wordNotFound=false;

for (int i=0;i<test.lenght;i++)
 for (int j=0;j<test2.length;j++){
   if (test[i].equals(test2[j])){
         wordNotFound=true
          break;
          }
     else wordNotFound=true;
  }
```

//// here i need the to change particular word back color not entire ritchtextbox

```
if (wordNotFound) richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    else richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

> im not comparing two text boxes im validating each word which is exist in both side or not. just like spell check taking dictionary as one richtextbox1. spell check [valid word] in richtextbox2. vice versa...

Comment: im validating each word which is exist in both side or not. just like spell check taking dictionary as one richtextbox1. spell check [valid word] in richtextbox2. vice versa...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare two richtextbox text using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782195/how-to-compare-two-richtextbox-text-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @0A0D its line by line comparison i need word by word comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var validWords = new HashSet<string>(new string[] { "a","c","e" });
string[] wordsToCheck = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

var result = wordsToCheck.Select(w => new
                {
                    Word = w,
                    IsValid = validWords.Contains(w)
                })
                .ToList();
```

If you are only interested in whether all words are valid or not, you can simple check it by

```
var isOK = wordsToCheck.All(w => validWords.Contains(w));
```

---

*PS: Of course, `new string[]{}`s should be replaced with `rtb.Split(....)` **

Answer (score 1):

If the words would be in the same order why bother with splitting at all?
If it will be ok, I'd do:

```
if (richtexbox1.text.equals(richtexbox1.text)){
 richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;
} else {
 richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

If not, and you want to find if both text boxes contain same word but in different order then:

```
    String[] test = richtextbox1.text.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
    String[] test2 = richtextbox2.text.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    bool wordNotFound=false;

    for (int i=0;i<test.lenght;i++)
     for (int j=0;j<test2.length;j++){
       if (test[i].equals(test2[j])){
             wordNotFound=false;
              break;
              }
         else wordNotFound=true;
      }

   if (wordNotFound) richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        else richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

Comment: In the inner loop it should be:
wordNotFound = false;

Comment: here the particular word color is not changed  it changed entire richtextbox

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[] test = richtextbox1.text.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
    String[] test2 = richtextbox2.text.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

is giving error;

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(string[],
>   System.StringSplitOptions)' has some invalid
>   arguments C:\Users\Saad\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\WindowsFormsApplication5\Form1.cs  60  29  WindowsFormsApplication5
>
> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'string[]'    C:\Users\Saad\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\WindowsFormsApplication5\Form1.cs  60  53  WindowsFormsApplication5

Answer (score -1):

You could compare each word in textbox1 with textbox2

```
for(int i = 0; i < stringarray1.length; i++)
{
 for(int j = 0; j < stringarray2.length; j++)
 {
   if(stringarray1[i] == stringarray2[j])
     // we have a match
 }
}
```

Comment: actually im not comparing two text boxes im validating each word which is exist in both side or not. just like spell check taking dictionary as one richtextbox1. spell check [valid word] in richtextbox2. vice versa...